# adobe illustrator script- printing custom size paper

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

we have at work an HP plotter and I'm trying to make a script that will print the job with the right paper size.

the width of the paper is 900mm and the height can be set as we want it to be but we have to do it manualy for every job.

I have written a script that prints the job on the HP plotter but I can't find a way to chek the artboard size to detrmain the printing orientation and print it at the size of the artboard + some space for the cutting.

here is what I have now:

```
var Doc = app.activeDocument;
var abActive = Doc.artboards[Doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

var bounds = abActive.artboardRect;

var left = bounds[0];
var top = bounds[1];
var right = bounds[2];
var bottom = bounds[3];

var Pheight = right - left;

//Lexmark 1
//HP 2
var Lexmark = app.printerList[1].name;
var HP = app.printerList[2].name;

var PaperA3 = printerList[2].printerInfo.paperSizes[1];

var printJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions();
var options = new PrintOptions();

var coordinateOptions = new PrintCoordinateOptions();
//coordinateOptions.fitToPage = true;
coordinateOptions.orientation = PrintOrientation.AUTOROTATE ;
options.coordinateOptions = coordinateOptions;

var printPaperOpts = new PrintPaperOptions();
printPaperOpts.name = PaperA3;
printPaperOpts.height = 600;
options.paperOptions = printPaperOpts;

options.printerName = HP;
options.printPreset = "HP";

Doc.print(options);
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Nope. couldn't solve it and I haven't found any info online.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand the problem a whole. Probably it's need to clarify some details.

For example here is the snippet to get a size of the active artboard and its orientation:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var artboard = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

const mm = 2.834645669;

var bounds = artboard.artboardRect;
var width  = Math.round((bounds[2] - bounds[0]) / mm);
var height = Math.round((bounds[1] - bounds[3]) / mm);

var landscape = (width > height) ? true : false;

alert('height = ' + height + ' mm\nwidth = ' + width + ' mm\nlandscape: ' + landscape);
```

[image]

This way you can get the numbers. The code is quite simple and obvious.

Is it enough? Let me know if you need help.

Comment: I tried to use your code buy it didn'y work. My printer has a roll of paper and not sheets so when I want to use it I have to select a custom paper size that will fit the job. the problem in my script is that no matter what I do, the height of the paper stays about 30CM.

I'm trying to figure out the paper options that will make it work.

Comment: My code just calculates and shows a size of current artboard in current file. It does the job file, but It has nothing to do with printer settings of your printer. The next step is to change the the printer preferences based on the artboard side and the orientation. I don't even sure for now if it's possible.

Comment: I tried changing many settings but nothing is working. What I will do for now is a pretty dirty job- I will create many printing profiles that will fit the sizes of my jobs and then I will make a script that will choose the right profile that fits the job.

Comment: Yes. I would do the same as a workaround. But it hard to me to help you since the exactly solution depends on the specific printer drivers I suppose. I didn't even managed to get sane results for my printers for now. The examples from the official docs don't work at all. The 'Error 1200' appears as soon as I try to get the printer list, etc. Illustrator's engine is a buggy beast.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script that will set a preset depending on the artboard size but it's not working and not because of my script. For some reason illustrator sets the paper size to A4 even when I set a diffrent size in the preset.

From reading online it has to be a problem with the printer drivers.